# In Tomcat 7.0\wtpwebapps Older files reflect

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I Cleaned the tomcat directory, published the server.I did project clean, then build project. 
Whatever I do the files in "wtpwebapps" folder is not updating.

Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat caches directory contents and certain file contents.

If you want to disable the cache, you'll need to set this configuration attribute on your web application's `<Resources>` element (usually in `META-INF/context.xml` within your WAR file or expanded-WAR directory structure):

```
<Resources cachingAllowed="false" />
```

For more information, see the [Tomcat Resources Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html).